# How to check if sim card is installed (sim state) or cell signal strength on connected bluetooth devices programmatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, telephonymanager, android-dialer

I'm developing a system dialer app for my android device, which can use a bluetooth-connected phone to make calls. So I need to know whether sim card is inserted or not or at least its cell signal level. I need this to show a special notification "there is no sim card".

Comment: There is no general method to do this that I'm aware of. Your Bluetooth connected phone would need to provide this information to you. I'm guessing you don't have another app installed on the remote phone?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes, there are no my special apps on the remote divices as this can be user's any phone

Comment: I don't think you can get this to work without a custom app installed on the devices... What would happen if you start a call via Bluetooth and the remote device does not have a SIM installed? Maybe you get a specific error message you could work with to show a message regarding the missing SIM

Comment: Anyway, how do you start the call? Are you posing as a hands free device?

Comment: Yes, this is something like a car multimedia system. Currently it starts the call, then after some seconds it ends the call (in case of no sim card presents)

Comment: hmh thats unfortunate... Let's hope someone else has another good idea

Answer (score -1):

You can use Telephony Manager and Phone State listener.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

tm.listen(new MyPhoneStateListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            int signalSupport = -signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
            Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "gsm signal--> " + signalSupport);

            if (signalSupport < 90) {
                Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Signal GSM : Good");

            } else if (signalSupport < 100) {
                Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Signal GSM : Avarage");

            } else if (signalSupport < 110) {
                Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Signal GSM : Weak");

            } else if (signalSupport < 120) {
                Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Signal GSM : Very weak");

            } else { //120 -> no sim/signal
                Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Signal GSM : Null");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does this differentiate sim state between the sim card of my device and the sim card of bluetooth-connected device ?

Comment: This is for getting sim card status of your device..i am unsure if there exists a method to get sim card info about bt connected device.